# Why is dot needed to make a cookie available among subdomains?

Tags: dns, cookies

We need to set the domain as `.example.com` to make it available for `*.example.com`,

but why not `example.com`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`example.com` means "exactly" `example.com` ; and nothing more.

If `example.com` was used to mean `*.example.com`, how would you set a cookie that's valid on `example.com` and not on `subsite.example.com` ?

Answer (score 0):

The dot at the beginning says it'll be available for all subdomains. It's just... needed :)

If you don't use the initial dot, you'd be telling it to be only available for example.com (not even www.example.com).